# Poor DCGAN performance when upgrading from keras to tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

**Update 1:** When removing the batch normalisation layers it works well. Apparently the way batch normalisation works was changed between iterations. Still investigating.

**Update 2:** Questions below report two possible remedies; changing the momentum value in batchnormalisation (this didn't work for me) and simply commenting out the batchnorm in the discriminator. Commenting out BN in the discriminator seems to work for me. No idea why yet.

Questions/links reporting similar problems:

[Poor Result with BatchNormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376226/poor-result-with-batchnormalization)

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56860/dc-gan-with-batch-normalization-not-working

[Keras train partial model issue (about GAN model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422646/keras-train-partial-model-issue-about-gan-model)

https://medium.com/@nagabhushansn95/using-batch-normalization-in-discriminator-is-making-my-dc-gan-model-to-not-work-8c0b4a869a2a

---

**Question Starts:**

I'm trying to run a DCGAN from "GANs in Action". The GAN generates images from the MNIST dataset.

The source code can be found here [GANs in action github page](https://github.com/GANs-in-Action/gans-in-action/blob/master/chapter-4/Chapter_4_DCGAN.ipynb)

**The code performs well and the generated images are good.**

When I change the source code so that it becomes compatible with `tf.keras` rather than `keras`, the **DCGAN model's ability to generate images becomes useless.**

**The following is the only bit of the code I've changed**. From:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

to:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

I've even tried to enforce tf_1 compatability with

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

-performance remains poor.

Why is this? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: I encountered this a while ago - if I recall correctly, default learning rate differs between tf.keras and keras.

I can't seem to find it anymore, but I believe tf.keras has a default of 1e-3 while keras has a default of 1. Not 100% sure, but worth checking.

Comment: thanks @StanleyZheng - I don't suppose you know which optimiser that's for? I'm using adam

Comment: The default for every optimizer - if you don't set lr, then learning rate will be different.

Comment: @StanleyZheng Batchnormalisation seems suspect, see my edit

Comment: Hmm, that's super interesting, never seen this before. Good job figuring that out, it would take me forever.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to import the previous version of the BatchNormalization by

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

And then use the original settings from the book. That worked for me.